# Spark : Scala mocking, Task not serializable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, mockito, spy

I am trying to use mockito for unit testing some scala code. I want to run spark locally, i.e. in my IntelliJ IDE. Here is a sample

```
class MyScalaSparkTests extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfter with MockitoSugar with java.io.Serializable{

  val configuration:SparkConf  = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("Your Application Name")
    .setMaster("local");
  val sc = new SparkContext(configuration);
  lazy val testSess = SparkSession.builder.appName("local_test").getOrCreate()
  test ("test service") {
    import testSess.implicits._
    // (1) init
    val testObject = spy(new MyScalaClass(<some args>))
    val testDf = testSess.emptyDataset[MyCaseClass1].toDF()
    testDf.union(Seq(MyCaseClass(<some args>)).toDF())
    testObject.testDataFrame = testDf
    val testSource = testSess.emptyDataset[MyCaseClass2].toDF()
    testSource.union(Seq(MyCaseClass2(<some args>)).toDF())
    testObject.setSourceDf(testSource)
    val testRes = testObject.someMethod()

    val r = testRes.take(1)
    println(r)

  }

}
```

so basically, here is what I am trying to do

`MyScalaClass` has `someMethod()` which compares data between two data frames called `testDataFrame` and `testSource`. It then returns another data frame which has the results. Now, in my unit test, I am spying on `MyScalaClass` to create `testObject`. Then I create `testDataFrame` and `testSource` and assign them to `testObject`. Finally, I call `testObject.someMethod()`.

Now in the debugger, at this line

```
val r = testRes.take(1)
```

I see that `testRes` is a `Dataset` hence something is being returned by the method. But when I try to `take` something from it in order to verify the results I get

```
Task not serializable
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
```

and further down the stacktrace

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.mockito.internal.creation.DelegatingMethod
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.mockito.internal.creation.DelegatingMethod, value: org.mockito.internal.creation.DelegatingMethod@a97f2bff)
    - field (class: org.mockito.internal.invocation.InterceptedInvocation, name: mockitoMethod, type: interface org.mockito.internal.invocation.MockitoMethod)
    - object (class org.mockito.internal.invocation.InterceptedInvocation, bSV2PartValidator.toString();)
    - field (class: org.mockito.internal.invocation.InvocationMatcher, name: invocation, type: interface org.mockito.invocation.Invocation)
    - object (class org.mockito.internal.invocation.InvocationMatcher, bSV2PartValidator.toString();)
    - field (class: org.mockito.internal.stubbing.InvocationContainerImpl, name: invocationForStubbing, type: interface org.mockito.invocation.MatchableInvocation)
    - object (class org.mockito.internal.stubbing.InvocationContainerImpl, invocationForStubbing: bSV2PartValidator.toString();)
    - field (class: org.mockito.internal.handler.MockHandlerImpl, name: invocationContainer, type: class org.mockito.internal.stubbing.InvocationContainerImpl)
    - object (class org.mockito.internal.handler.MockHandlerImpl, org.mockito.internal.handler.MockHandlerImpl@47c019d7)
    - field (class: org.mockito.internal.handler.NullResultGuardian, name: delegate, type: interface org.mockito.invocation.MockHandler)
    - object (class org.mockito.internal.handler.NullResultGuardian, org.mockito.internal.handler.NullResultGuardian@7222e168)
    - field (class: org.mockito.internal.handler.InvocationNotifierHandler, name: mockHandler, type: interface org.mockito.invocation.MockHandler)
    - object (class org.mockito.internal.handler.InvocationNotifierHandler, org.mockito.internal.handler.InvocationNotifierHandler@1e4f8430)
    - field (class: org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor, name: handler, type: interface org.mockito.invocation.MockHandler)
    - object (class org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor, org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor@34d08905)
    - field (class: com.walmart.labs.search.signals.validators.BSV2PartValidator$MockitoMock$213785213, name: mockitoInterceptor, type: class org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor)
    - object (class com.walmart.labs.search.signals.validators.BSV2PartValidator$MockitoMock$213785213, com.walmart.labs.search.signals.validators.BSV2PartValidator$MockitoMock$213785213@7f289126)
    - field (class: com.walmart.labs.search.signals.validators.BSV2PartValidator$$anonfun$1, name: $outer, type: class com.walmart.labs.search.signals.validators.BSV2PartValidator)
    - object (class com.walmart.labs.search.signals.validators.BSV2PartValidator$$anonfun$1, <function1>)
    - element of array (index: 1)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 7)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8, name: references$1, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8, <function2>)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
    ... 78 more
```

What am i doing wrong? Is it even possible to spy on or mock spark behavior in IDE?

Answer (score 4):

Mocks are not serialisable by default, as it's usually a code smell in unit testing

You can try enabling serialisation by creating the mock like `mock[MyType](Mockito.withSettings().serializable())` and see what happens when spark tries to use it.

BTW, I recommend you to use [mockito-scala](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala) instead of the traditional mockito as it may save you some other problems

Comment: But is this an answer or not?

Comment: thanks, but if i use `Mockito.withSettings().serializable()` turns out i cannot spy on my class. I get `Error:(26, 14) value testDataFrame is not a member of (path.to.MyScalaClass, org.mockito.MockSettings)
    testObject.testDataFrame = testDf`

Comment: by the way, i could not find any good examples of spying on classes with mockito-scala. can you please point me to some?

Comment: Spying in mockito-scala works exactly the same as regular mockito... What you can try is a mock with delegate witch is how spyLambda works, i.e. `Mockito.mock(classOf[MyType], Mockito.withSettings().serializable().defaultAnswer(AdditionalAnswers.delegatesTo(new MyScalaClass(<some args>))))`

Comment: If it works let me know and I'll try to give it a better API in mockito-scala